# Is the value for ProjectGuid in a .csproj file supposed to be unique?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on several C# projects created by others under Visual Studio 2015. I found that the following line appears in the .csproj files of two projects:

```
<ProjectGuid>{1CB310F7-B9BE-4E66-9DA5-4BAE2AB8055A}</ProjectGuid>
```

Does it mean that the two projects have the same project GUID?

GUID is an acronym for 'Globally Unique Identifier', so I thought different projects should have different values for their project GUID's.

Is the value for ProjectGuid in a .csproj file supposed to be unique?

Thanks.

Comment: hold on while we turn on the jon skeet signal...

Comment: The acronym of a GUID/UUID does not *mandate* values or usages of such are unique - rather, that when carefully chosen, the values can be held unique within a given domain due to the value space and generation process(es).

Comment: @Felipe how do you do that?

Comment: This is not a GUID, it is a HUID, a Hopefully Unique ID.  No hope when a programmer copies/renames a project file.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one of the projects was copied from another initially. `ProjectGuid` in project files should uniquely identify the project. It is safe to change it, if you update project file and all solution / project files that reference it.

There's also another project related guid - project type GUID, used to be in `ProjectTypeGuids`, which is a project type and is not meant to be unique. Now it is present only in solution files.

You can find *project type* GUIDs meaning in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Projects`.